# Simple XmlHttpRequest to be used with web workers

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a very basic XMLHttpRequest function that would be used with web workers.

I would like to know how I could improve it to handle possible errors better:

```
var ThreadedXhrRequest = function(url) {
    var worker = new Worker("xhrWorker.js");
    worker.postMessage([url]);
    worker.onmessage = function(d) {
        console.log(d.data)
    }
}
```

xhrWorker.js

```
onmessage = function(e) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", e[0], true);
    xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            postMessage(xhr.responseText);
            close();
         }
    }
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are overwriting the `worker.onmessage` function rather than calling it. Without seeing what `postMessage()` does, it would appear that this code wouldn't actually do anything.  Consider adding more context to your code in post.

Comment: worker.onmessage just log xhr.responseText to the console. It was based on this example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/onmessage